# Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host

Tags: android, x86-64, amd, android-emulator

Ни в какую не запускается **эмулятор** в Android studio. Процессор **amd** athlon silver 3050u with radeon graphics.
Логи:

```
2022-07-29 12:00:53,239 [5636174]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 31 - C:\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_31 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-07-29 12:00:53,479 [5636414]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 31 - PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Android\sdk]! 
2022-07-29 12:00:53,480 [5636415]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 31 - Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-07-29 12:00:53,482 [5636417]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 31 - Process finished with exit code 1
```

Расположение файлов:
C:\Android
C:\Sdk
**Переменные среды** windows:

```
ANDROID_AVD_HOME    C:\Users\Андрей\.android\avd
ANDROID_HOME        C:\Sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT    C:\Sdk
```

Установленные SDK:

```
Android SDK Build-Tools 33
Android Emulator
Android Emulator Hypervizor Driver for AMD Processors (installer)
Android SDK Platform-Tools
Android SDK Tools
Google Play services
```

Переустановить Android emulator пробовал. Свободного места на диске достаточно. Android SDK Location в SDK manager установлена корректно. Виртуализация процессора включена. Драйвер гипервизора установлен и работает.
**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**
Немного изменил расположение файлов и поменял переменные среды:
[image: Переменные среды windows]

**Новые логи**:

```
2022-08-01 17:04:53,519 [ 416150]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - C:\Soft\SDK_Android\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_5_API_29 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,816 [ 416447]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host. 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,816 [ 416447]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,819 [ 416450]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - Process finished with exit code 1 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,821 [ 416452]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1 
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code 1
2022-08-01 17:04:53,822 [ 416453]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,822 [ 416453]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,822 [ 416453]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - OS: Windows 10 
2022-08-01 17:04:53,822 [ 416453]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 5 API 29 - Last Action:  
2022-08-01 17:04:57,634 [ 420265]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=My Application, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=C:\projectAndr)RunManager took 46 ms, ToolWindowManager took 18 ms, XDebuggerManager took 24 ms
```

Comment: попробуйте здесь посмотреть - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61595161/emulator-panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value-f-a

Comment: Переименовал переменные среды, как в ответе, но появилась новая ошибка: PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host

Comment: а что у вас за железо на машине вообще стоит? по-моему с amd у эмулятора возникают сложности в работе

Comment: amd athlon silver 3050u with radeon graphics

Comment: доки тут смотрели - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#:~:text=Open%20Tools%2D%3ESDK%20Manager.,Hypervisor%20Driver%20for%20AMD%20processors. ?

Comment: Сделал всё точно по этой инструкции. Ошибка та же

Comment: В логах ошибка `PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host`, похоже вы установили другой образ системы, у которой архитектура `arm64`. Установите через sdkmanager образ системы в соответствии с вашей архитектурой процессора `x86_64`. Вам нужно установить, например, пакет `system-images;android-31;default;x86_64`.

Comment: `windows включил Hyper-V, песочницу windows и платформу виртуальной машины.`...а зачем?

Comment: @vitidev, простите за устаревшую информацию. Они не нужны и я их отключил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в логах следующая ошибка:

> PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host

Она указывает на то, что вы используете образ системы для архитектуры `arm64`, а архитектура вашего процессора — `x86_64`.

Проверьте через AVD Manager (Device Manager), что вы используете образ `system-images;android-31;default;x86_64`, а не `system-images;android-31;default;arm64-v8a`.

Чтобы установить конкретный образ, можно воспользоваться консольной версией SDK Manager.

(Чтобы установить консольные утилиты, в Android Studio перейдите в SDK Manager -> SDK Tools и установите Command-line Tools, либо скачайте [Command-line Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools) с официального сайта)

С помощью консольного SDK Manager, установите нужный образ из командной строки:

```
sdkmanager "system-images;android-31;default;x86_64"
```

Создайте новый виртуальный девайс при помощи AVD Manager:

```
avdmanager create avd -n "MyDevice" -k "system-images;android-31;default;x86_64" -d pixel
```

Запустите эмулятор:

```
emulator -avd "MyDevice"
```

Comment: Ваше решение помогло мне! SDK Manager в android studio не отображает в доступных для скачивания образах образы для архитектуры моего процессора